# I bring villagers to my compound but they keep going back to their village. Why is that?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I abduct villagers via minecart and take them to my place which has a bed and plenty of jobs but they keep going back to their village no matter how far it is.

Is there something I need to do?

Answer (score 26):

Break their original beds and workstations! Villagers claim one bed and one workstation each, and can go quite a way to return to them. Only if their originals are broken or inaccessible (and time for work or sleep came, respectively, and they failed to pathfind to them) - and there are new, unclaimed ones available, they'll take them.

Comment: So no need to "abduct" them?  Just make a bed, then break their original bed and they'll find the new one automatically?

Comment: @freedomn-m  They have a somewhat limited radius of search for the new ones, so depends on the distance. But you can abduct them through a "breadcrumb trail" of beds or workstations as they proceed to next one as you break the previous.

Comment: I assume you know the terrible efficiency by the "breadcrumb trail" compared to minecarts or even just boats :)

Comment: Does this imply that if you only break their workstation but leave their bed intact before abducting them, you can have villagers commuting between their home village and your compound every day? :D

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Possibly, with caveats which chunks are applying, distance (after certain distance they are unable to pathfind and lose the binding), and the fact a villager commuting back home after dark is likely to have his face eaten by a zombie.

Comment: @iBug Largely depends on the distances. 1000+ blocks - ugh. But if you want a villager to enter the cell of an iron farm, 40 blocks away, this is way easier than minecarts.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to SF's excellent point, I would also suggest that you make sure at least one bed is quite close to the villager when you drop them off.  I ran into this problem setting up two villages on islands, where the beach is much lower than the houses I had built, and villagers would always attempt to return to their villages or just roam randomly until I placed a bed on the beach.

When I placed a bed on the beach, they would instantly claim that bed upon leaving the boat, and then would eventually claim other beds when they wandered around looking for jobs (allowing me to bring other villagers using the same method).